# Unity 2D graphical glitch cuts sprite diagonally

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

While making a game in unity, we found a graphical glitch that only happens on one of our mobile devices (a htc) where the screen will be oddly sliced by a triangle as shown in this image; 
[image: Character on the left of the screen is halved]

I've searched online but found no problem. We're using unity 2D, it only does it on the HTC but we have no idea why. 
The background is a 3D quad with a texture wrapped around it (so we can make it move with the character when the character is running, without having one large background). 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a camera culling issue.  Had the exact same thing happen to me.  More than likely, you need to adjust the Canvas that character is on, so that it is closer to the z-index range of your Camera.

[image]

Comment: So we should move everything closer to the camera?

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the swordguy gameobject inspector properties? I imagine you are using an orthographic camera?  And yeah, the issue for me, was that the Canvas component was too far away from the camera.

Comment: We changed the z axis and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem.  Feel free to send me consultation money. :)

Comment: Maybe reducing your camera far plane will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I had this painful clueless issue before. But I did resolve it. Probably your camera is at z:-10 and everything other is at z:0. Try to bring camera closer to object like set camera's Z to -1.

Answer (score 1):

don't keep your background and your image in the same position . 
keep them far away from each other .

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide any new information; there's already an accepted answer provides the same information with a more precise explanation & solution.